# Code does not compile - linked lists, sort list to ascending order

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote a code of getting a linked list with numbers, and trying to make the list as ascending series. Unfortunately the code is not complied and I don't know why.

I have tried to play with the pointers and references but I cant put my hand on what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ListNode {
public:
  ListNode(const int &info) : data(info), nextPtr(0) {}

  int getData() const { return data; }
  ListNode *getNext() const { return nextPtr; }
  void setNext(ListNode *next) { nextPtr = next; }

private:
  int data;
  ListNode *nextPtr;
};

ListNode sort(ListNode &temp) {
  ListNode *first = &temp;
  ListNode *curr = first;
  ListNode *next = curr->getNext();
  ListNode *found = 0;

  while (curr->getNext() != 0) {
    if (curr->getData() > next->getData()) {
      if (curr == first) {
        first = next;
        found = curr;
      }

      else {
        curr->setNext(next->getNext());
        found = next;
      }

      break;
    }

    curr = next;
    next = next->getNext();
  }

  curr = first;
  next = curr->getNext();

  while (curr->getNext() != 0) {
    if (curr->getData() <= found->getData() &&
        found->getData() < next->getData()) {
      curr->setNext(found);
      found->setNext(next);
      break;
    }

    curr = next;
    next = next->getNext();
  }

  return *first;
}

void print(ListNode &temp) {
  ListNode *curr = &temp;

  while (curr != 0) {
    cout << curr->getData() << " ";
    curr = curr->getNext();
  }

  cout << endl;
}

int main1() {
  ListNode a(2);
  ListNode b(5);
  ListNode c(8);
  ListNode d(13);
  ListNode e(18);
  ListNode f(7);
  ListNode g(21);

  a.setNext(&b);
  b.setNext(&c);
  c.setNext(&d);
  d.setNext(&e);
  e.setNext(&f);
  f.setNext(&g);

  print(a);
  print(sort(a));

  return 0;
}
```

I have checked hundred times and do not know why this code is not compiling.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: E0461, and C2664

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172033/invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-of-type)

Comment: ***E0461, and C2664*** Next time please add the exact text of the error message. Most users will not know these codes without having to google. You can get the text of the error message in the Output Tab of Visual Studio. And yes I mean Output Tab and not the errors list. The output tab is in a more verbose format and also it is in plain text.

Comment: actually i am new here i barely succeed open a question forum. haha. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` should return a pointer to the node, so return `first` instead of `*first` and change the return type to `ListNode*`. Then change `print(sort(a))` to `print(*sort(a))`. See it run here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3e72983e83f6914

Comment: @LORINECHERRY Glad I could help. And just to let you know we normally don't use references to nodes but instead *pointers*, and the functions that work on linked lists usually access those nodes through pointers. So everywhere you are accessing a node it should be through a pointer to that node, not a reference like what you're doing in your code. For example, the print function should take a `ListNode*` instead of a `ListNode&`.

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: @LORINECHERRY It allows you to allocate and deallocate memory dynamically. There are also no such thing as "null" references. So if you have a function called `countNodes(Node&)` it's basically saying that there has to be at least one node in the list, because there's no way to pass an empty list, which is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
     #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode(const int &info) :data(info), nextPtr(0)
    {
    }

    int getData() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    ListNode * getNext() const
    {
        return nextPtr;
    }
    void setNext(ListNode * next)
    {
        nextPtr = next;
    }
private:
    int data;
    ListNode *nextPtr;
};

ListNode sort(ListNode &temp)
{
    ListNode *first = &temp;
    ListNode *curr = first;
    ListNode *next = curr->getNext();
    ListNode *found = 0;

    while (curr->getNext() != 0)
    {
        if (curr->getData() > next->getData())
        {
            if (curr == first)
            {
                first = next;
                found = curr;
            }

            else
            {
                curr->setNext(next->getNext());
                found = next;
            }

            break;
        }

        curr = next;
        next = next->getNext();
    }

    curr = first;
    next = curr->getNext();

    while (curr->getNext() != 0)
    {
        if (curr->getData() <= found->getData() && found->getData() < next->getData())
        {
            curr->setNext(found);
            found->setNext(next);
            break;
        }

        curr = next;
        next = next->getNext();
    }

    return *first;
}
```

*You are passing a temporary(rvalue) to a function which expects an lvalue*

```
    void print(const ListNode &temp)
{


const ListNode * curr = &temp;

    while (curr != 0)
    {
        cout << curr->getData() << " ";
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }

    cout << endl;
}
//I am expecting main() here , I think this is what you meant.

int main()
{
    ListNode a(2);
    ListNode b(5);
    ListNode c(8);
    ListNode d(13);
    ListNode e(18);
    ListNode f(7);
    ListNode g(21);

    a.setNext(&b);
    b.setNext(&c);
    c.setNext(&d);
    d.setNext(&e);
    e.setNext(&f);
    f.setNext(&g);

    print(a);
    print(sort(a));

    return 0;
    }
```